# MongoDB Embedded Documents and C# / POCO

Tags: c#, mongodb, model-view-controller, poco, bson

I'm relatively new to both C# / MVC and MongoDB, and I'm just starting to get a POCO implementation working right.  But I'm still unsure how I can map C# objects to a more complex BSON document.

I'd like to see some examples on how to do basic CRUD operations on BSON documents that have embedded documents and arrays, etc.  Also, I'm very particular on efficiency, and I'd like to make sure that I'm not replacing the full BSON document (potentially 16MB in size), and only make changes to the targeted child documents (embedded docs).

For example, here's a MongoDB collection that I'd like to do all sorts of CRUD operations on; (completely fictional example..)

```
    // customers collection
   { _id: new ObjectID(), 
    name: "Joe", 
    purchased: [
      {dte: ISODate("2015-01-01"), prod_id: ObjectId("xxx"), price: 256.95, desc: "Classic iPod"}, 
      {prod_id: ObjectId("yyy"), price: 19.95, desc: "Classic iPod earbuds"}
    ], 
    last_store: {address: "123 Abc St.", latlong: [123.234235, -9.0234234]}, 
    used_coupons: [
      {coupon_id: ObjectId("123"), 
       disc_type: "percent", 
       disc_value: 5, 
       applied_to: [
             { prod_id: ObjectId("xxx"), saved: 12.85 }, 
             { prod_id: ObjectId("yyy"), saved: 4.12 }
        ]}, 
    {coupon_id: ObjectId("098"), 
       disc_type: "usd", 
       disc_value: 20, 
       applied_to: [
             { prod_id: ObjectId("xxx"), saved: 20 }
        ]}
    ]
    }
```

Can anyone please demonstrate to me how to map to this type of complex structure?  Also a couple basic `$push`, `$addToSet` or `$elemMatch` examples would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

I looked around and found a great tutorial that goes through making a POCO / MongoDB class library and has some embedded document examples.  This is the last of a 3 instalment series.  Here's the link:

[(Dr.Dobb's) MongoDB with C#: Deep Dive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160126042314/https://www.drdobbs.com/database/mongodb-with-c-deep-dive/240152181?pgno=1)

Here's an excerpt;

```
namespace RetrogamesWeb.Data.Services
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
 
    using Entities;
    using MongoDB.Bson;
    using MongoDB.Driver;
    using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;
 
    public class PlayerService: EntityService<Player>
    {
        public void AddScore(string playerId, Score score)
        {
            var playerObjectId = new ObjectId(playerId);
 
            var updateResult = this.MongoConnectionHandler.MongoCollection.Update(
                    Query<Player>.EQ(p => p.Id, playerObjectId), 
                    Update<Player>.Push(p => p.Scores, score),
                    new MongoUpdateOptions
                    {
                        WriteConcern = WriteConcern.Acknowledged
                    });
 
            if (updateResult.DocumentsAffected == 0)
            {
                //// Something went wrong
                 
            }
        }
 
        public IEnumerable<Player> GetPlayersDetails(int limit, int skip)
        {
            var playersCursor = this.MongoConnectionHandler.MongoCollection.FindAllAs<Player>()
                .SetSortOrder(SortBy<Player>.Ascending(p => p.Name))
                .SetLimit(limit)
                .SetSkip(skip)
                .SetFields(Fields<Player>.Include(p => p.Id, p => p.Name));
            return playersCursor;
        }
 
        public override void Update(Player entity)
        {
            var updateResult = this.MongoConnectionHandler.MongoCollection.Update(
                    Query<Player>.EQ(p => p.Id, entity.Id),
                    Update<Player>.Set(p => p.Name, entity.Name)
                        .Set(p => p.Gender, entity.Gender),
                    new MongoUpdateOptions
                    {
                        WriteConcern = WriteConcern.Acknowledged
                    });
 
            if (updateResult.DocumentsAffected == 0)
            {
                //// Something went wrong
 
            }
        }
    }
}
```